# CDT 6 (eclipse galileo) snow leopard debugging issue

Tags: debugging, osx-snow-leopard, eclipse-cdt

I upgrade to snow leopard and Xcode 3.2 this week, and since that, I'm having problems with CDT. I tried this in CDT 5 (Ganymede) and CDT 6 (Galileo).

If I try to debug the application using launcher "Standard Create Process Launcher", it delays about 10 seconds to actually get in the debugging breakpoint, which is very odd.

If I use as launcher "GDB (DSF) Create Process Launcher" it works at the speed I expect, but the variables tab that shows me what's going on in the current scope show the variable values like that:

"Failed to execute MI command:
-var-update 1 var2
Error message from debugger back end:
Variable object not found
Failed to execute MI command:
-var-update 1 var1
Error message from debugger back end:
Variable object not found"

I don't have any idea how to solve one or the other issue, any of them will let me work up to speed.